# Creating custom views based off of a template

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistackview

Rights now I have created a UIStackView filled with different labels and images that are generic. This UIStackView is displayed when a user selects a row from my tableView. I would like to have it so that the UIStackView can be altered depending on what row is selected in my tableView.

Example: A user selects row 1 of section 1 and is brought to a screen showing information unique to the row of the tableview in my UIStackView.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code that displays my tableView.

```
import UIKit

struct Data {
   var sectionTitle = String()
   var rowTitles = [String]()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var dataArray = [Data(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]),
    Data(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["row 1"]),
    Data(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2"])
]
var searchArray = [Data]()
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let labelValueImages: LabelValueImagePairs = [
    (image: image, label: "row 1", value: "This is data."),
    (image: image, label: "row 2", value: "This is data.")
]

    let myStackView = MyStackView(labelsAndValues: labelValueImages)
    view.addSubview(myStackView)
    myStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchArray[section].rowTitles.count
    } else {
        return dataArray[section].rowTitles.count
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
    cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
    if searching {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell!
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchArray.count
    } else {
        return dataArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return dataArray[section].sectionTitle
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var data: Data?
if searching {
    data = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
} else {
    data = self.dataArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
}
    let destVC = SecondViewController(data: data)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
}

}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        searching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        searching = true
        searchArray = dataArray.filter({$0.sectionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased()) || $0.rowTitles.map{$0.lowercased()}.contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for the new viewController and the UIStackView.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var data: Data!
var dataView: DataView { return self.view as! DataView}

init(data: Data) {
    self.data = data
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func loadView() {
    self.view = MyStackView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }


typealias LabelValueImagePairs = [(image: UIImage?, label: String, value: String?]

class MyStackView: UIStackView {

var labelsAndValues: LabelValueImagePairs?
func setupViews() {

    distribution = .fill
    alignment = .fill
    axis = .vertical

    labelsAndValues?.forEach({ (labelValuePair) in

        let labelLabel = UILabel()
        labelLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labelLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .semibold)
        labelLabel.textAlignment = .center
        labelLabel.text = labelValuePair.label
        labelLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        addArrangedSubview(labelLabel)

        if let value = labelValuePair.value {
            let valueLabel = UILabel()
            valueLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            valueLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .light)
            valueLabel.textAlignment = .center
            valueLabel.text = value
            valueLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            valueLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
            addArrangedSubview(valueLabel)
        }

        if let image = labelValuePair.image {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image.size.height).isActive = true
            addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        }

        let spacer = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 25)))
        addArrangedSubview(spacer)

    })

}

convenience init(labelsAndValues: LabelValueImagePairs) {
    self.init()
    self.labelsAndValues = labelsAndValues
    setupViews()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupViews()
}

}
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Changing the values of the stack view that correspond to their respected row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly basic example of a dynamic vertical `UIStackView`.  The stack view takes in an array of tuples, each with a label, optional value, and optional image.  The stack view will create the appropriate views from the passed in array and add them as arranged subviews.  This example just shows the stack view in a controller's `viewDidLoad` but it could be placed anywhere you are able to show a view.  Any questions, let me know.

The StackView:

```
typealias LabelValueImagePairs = [(label:String, value: String?, image: UIImage?)]

class MyStackView: UIStackView {

    var labelsAndValues: LabelValueImagePairs?
    func setupViews() {

        distribution = .fill
        alignment = .fill
        axis = .vertical

        labelsAndValues?.forEach({ (labelValuePair) in

            let labelLabel = UILabel()
            labelLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            labelLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .semibold)
            labelLabel.textAlignment = .center
            labelLabel.text = labelValuePair.label
            labelLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
            addArrangedSubview(labelLabel)

            if let value = labelValuePair.value {
                let valueLabel = UILabel()
                valueLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                valueLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .light)
                valueLabel.textAlignment = .center
                valueLabel.text = value
                valueLabel.numberOfLines = 0
                valueLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
                addArrangedSubview(valueLabel)
            }

            if let image = labelValuePair.image {
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image.size.height).isActive = true
                addArrangedSubview(imageView)
            }

            let spacer = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 25)))
            addArrangedSubview(spacer)

        })

    }

    convenience init(labelsAndValues: LabelValueImagePairs) {
        self.init()
        self.labelsAndValues = labelsAndValues
        setupViews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupViews()
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let labelValueImages: LabelValueImagePairs = [
            (label: "First Name:", value: "John", image: nil),
            (label: "Last Name:", value: "Doe", image: nil),
            (label: "Age:", value: "25", image: nil),
            (label: "Avatar:", value: nil, image: UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)))
        ]

        let myStackView = MyStackView(labelsAndValues: labelValueImages)
        view.addSubview(myStackView)
        myStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

[image: StackView Result]

edit:

For your additional question on how to get the correct data in the `didSelect` row.  You need to get the `Data` object for the given `IndexPath` using it's `section` and `row` properties the same way you do in your `cellForRowAt`.

```
var data: Data?

if searching {
    data = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
} else {
    data = self.dataArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I use this information so that when a tableview cell is selected it shows these new stack views?

Comment: Push or present the view controller in your tableView's `didSelectRow` delegate method.

Comment: I still can't get the row to display information based upon what row is clicked. Right now it only displays the information of the first stack view for every row. I've edited my code up above to match what I have now. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I've tried implementing this, but I think I have the format wrong. Can you check it?

Comment: in your `SecondViewController` you are using hard coded values and not the `data` that you passed into the controller.  Trying setting a breakpoint or printing out data, you look to be passing it correctly in the `didSelectRow`

Comment: In my didSelectRow I have an error that says 'Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Data' on the line 'data = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]'.

Comment: Change the `var data: Data?` to `var data: String?` will get get you the value for the cell, but what are you expecting to get?  Your next controller is initialized with a `Data` object, but your array of `Data` coorelates with the table sections not each individual cell.

Comment: So how would I change this code so that one value from the labelValueImagePairs is passed instead and matches its respected section in the tableview?